# Where is the database file from redmine after using the defaultinstallation?

Tags: 12.04, mysql, phpmyadmin, redmine

After I installed redmine, I have a database called redmine and through phpmyadmin I can take a backup etc. , but I can't find the default location of it. Where is it placed? Any Idea?

Does mysql store it somewhere or is it done by redmine ? I tried to find it using "locate" without any success, since I don't know if the DB name is as well the filename.

Any help is upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It's managed all by mysql  so it's under `var/lib/mysql/DATABASENAME`